# How to properly do a numerical filter in AWK when "NA" are present?

Tags: bash, awk, filtering

I have a table `myfile` in which one column with mostly numerical values, has some "NA" in it. When I try to filter the data based on values greater than 1, awk does not remove the "NA" values. Sample code below:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' $myfile
NA
14.69
NA
9.84
4.46
4.22
64.285
7.535
1.305

$ awk '$1>1' $myfile
NA
14.69
NA
9.84
4.46
4.22
64.285
7.535
1.305
```

What is the proper way to use numerical filters with awk when there are also "NA"s or "nan"s as values in addition to numbers for a given column?

Comment: If you can have `+nan` or `+inf` (or negative) in your data then include them in your example as some awks will recognize them as numeric.

Comment: `awk '$1 != "NA" && $1 > 1' file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:

```bash
awk '$1+0>1' file

14.69
9.84
4.46
4.22
64.285
7.535
1.305
```

`$1+0` will convert each value to numeric before comparing it so for `"NA"` it makes it `0`.

Comment: In general in awk to check if a first column is numeric, one can use: `awk '$1+0 == $1` and to combine both conditions use: `awk '$1+0 == $1 && $1 > 1'`

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
NA
14.69
NA
9.84
4.46
4.22
64.285
7.535
1.305
```

then

```
awk '$1=="NA"{next}$1>1' file.txt
```

gives output

```
14.69
9.84
4.46
4.22
64.285
7.535
1.305
```

Explanation: if 1st field value is `NA` go to `next` line i.e. skip that line, then print only lines where 1st field value is greater than `1`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Any awk would be able to do this, it's not specific to GNU awk

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
NA
14.69
-NaN\n+nan\nNAN 
9.84
4.46
4.22\n-inf\n+INF
64.285
7.535
1.305' | gtee >( gcat -b >&2 ) |
```

---

```
gawk '($1 - $1)  < (1 < +$1)' 
mawk '($1 - $1) != (1 < +$1)'
```

---

```
     1  NA
     2  14.69
     3  -NaN
     4  +nan
     5  NAN
     6  9.84
     7  4.46
     8  4.22
     9  -inf
    10  +INF
    11  64.285
    12  7.535
    13  1.305
14.69
9.84
4.46
4.22
64.285
7.535
1.305
```

You can use this compare combo can get rid of all the `NA`s, `NaN`s, and `inf(inities)`

Because `gawk`s and `mawk`s handle `NaN`-compares slightly differently, the syntax also diverges ever so slightly.